# How to make text transition with an image slider using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using Bootstrap's image carousel component in an HTML project with an interval of 7000ms. Their CSS and Javascript bundle with Popper is installed via CDN. Above the carousel, I have an h3 tag as a placeholder image title with an ID for targeting in JavaScript. Below the carousel, I have a p tag as a placeholder image description also with an ID. I want the image title and description to change with the image and I'm not sure of the best approach.

So far, I've created two variables by targeting the ids of the placeholder title and description tags using document.querySelector(); and two arrays of strings - one for the image and one for the description. I then created a function and used forEach(); to loop through both arrays, then redefined the title and description variables with the looped values and used the .innerHTML method to change what is displayed on the webpage. For both the title and description, only the last value in each array is showing, and it's not changing with the image. I don't know how to do the animation part in JavaScript, but I'd like to try. Any help is much appreciated!

[carousel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3no4X.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using bootstrap try from here
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

i mostly prefer https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/